# Perl - How to omit lines from a text file?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a text file, and I'm looking to omit some of the lines from the text file, and use that string to create a new file. The nice thing is that my text file starts the text chunk that I need with a line that includes "START" and ends with "END".

For example, my text file looks like:

```
1
2
3
Start
4
5
6
End
7
8
Start
9
10
End
```

The desired output would be two strings that I can output into text files that look like:

```
Start
4
5
6
End
```

```
Start
9
10
End
```

What I currently have so far:

```
open(RH, '<', $fileName) or die $!;

while(<RH>) {
    #print $_;
    chomp $_;
    if ($_ eq 'START') {
        $str = "$str"."$_\n";
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to continue.

EDIT:
I answered this question using:

```
$cmd = q(awk '/Start/,/End/ {print}' foo.txt);
my $output = qx($cmd);
my @cards = split (/(?<=\End)/, $output);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some of Perl's heritage from AWK and just do this (assuming your file is called foo.txt)

```
perl -ne'print if /Start/../End/' foo.txt
```

The expression `/Start/../End/` means "at the first line that matches `/Start/` up to the next line that matches `/End/`.

The equivalent code for awk would be

```
awk '/Start/,/End/ {print}' foo.txt
```

Comment: How would I use this if I wanted to use these lines in my perl script?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Read the entire file into a string `$str`:
open my $fh, '<', 'file_name' or die "Can't open file $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

while ($str =~ m{\n(START\n.*\nEND)\n}msg) {
    # Do something with each START...END set of lines
    print "$str\n";
}
```

Notes:

- I'm not sure of all the details.
- The `local $/`; might be done by something like `undef $/;`
- Adjust the parens to avoid capturing 'START' and 'END'.

Comment: `$/ = undef;` is better than `undef $/;`, and `local $/;` the best since it's localized.

Comment: Not sure if this is working properly. I would assume that your code sample prints out my wanted output, but nothing gets printed out to the terminal unfortunately.

Before the while loop, the text file gets properly loaded into $str, but the while loop isn't functioning properly.

Comment: @NelsonSwasono - I get confused about when to use /m vs /s -- remove either one.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work, you don't have /m or /s in your sample

Comment: @NelsonSwasono - TIMTOWTDI  -- I like to say `=~ m{...}` instead of `=~ /.../`.  That leads to `=~ m{...}msg` instead of `=~ /.../msg`.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Poz '(?ms)^Start.*?^End\n' in_file
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.
`-z` : Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Thus, you can match newlines in the input.

`(?ms)` : Enable the `m` and `s` [pattern-match modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns), to allow multiline matches, and to allow `.` to match a newline, respectively.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 0):

Use `..` as a "flip-flop" operator.

```
# Switch to a lexical filehandle
# (as this is modern best practice)
open(my $rh, '<', $fileName) or die $!;

# Open an output filehandle
my $x = 1;
open my $out, '>', "$filename.out.$x" or die $!;

while(<$rh>) {
  print $out $_ if /Start/ .. /End/;

  # Open a new output file if we've seen 'End'
  if (/End/) {
    ++$x;
    open my $out, '>', "$filename.out.$x" or die $!;
  }
}
```